# Euler sequence, exact sequence and Blow Up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

In $ X = \mathbb{P}^{n}$ we have the Euler sequence: $$0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(1)^{\oplus (n+1)} \longrightarrow T_{X} \longrightarrow 0 $$

Let $Y \subset X$ be a smooth subvariety and $\pi: \widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$  the morphism of blow up along of $Y$.

Is there an exact sequence in $\widetilde{X}$ analogous to the Euler sequence in $X$?

1) Is $\widetilde{X}$ an algebraic variety? Is it projective?

2) Is Bott's formula valid for $\widetilde{X}$?

Sorry if my questions are trivial to you, but I am a beginner in Algebraic Geometry.

**About exact sequence**:

3) What are the references where I can find exact sequences after a blow up along a smooth subvariety?

4) More precisely, I would like to learn more about exact sequences in $\widetilde{X}$ and later learn to calculate cohomologies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is Bott formula ? Is it $H^i(\Bbb P^n, \Omega_j) = \Bbb C$ if $0 \leq i =j \leq n$ and $0$ else ? (If yes, I does not holds in general. I'm almost sure it never holds in fact).

Comment: Two notes: (1.) $\widetilde{X}$ is again a projective variety, this is proven in Hartshorne, II Proposition 7.16. (2.) The pull-back of a SES of locally free sheaves is always exact. Algebraically, this corresponds to the fact that free modules are flat. However, that will of course not give you the sheaf $T_{\widetilde{X}}$.

Comment: Hi, Nicolas. The boot formula I refer to is found in the book: Vector Bundle on Complex Projective Space. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Nicolas. If Bott's formula is not valid, then I will need exact sequences to take the exact long sequence in cohomology,  Do you know references that help me in exact sequences associated with blow up? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, red_trumper. Is $\widetilde{X}$ an algebraic variety? Is there any relationship between $T_{X}$ and $T_{\widetilde{X}}$ ? Thank for your response.

Comment: The issue is that tangent sheaf doesnot behave well with respect to morphisms so in general there may not exist pullback morphisms between tangent sheaves. There does exists a SES $0 \rightarrow \pi^*\Omega_{X} \rightarrow \Omega_{\widetilde{X}} \rightarrow i_*\Omega_{E/Y} \rightarrow 0$, where $i$ is the inclusion of the exceptional locus $E$ of the blowup $\pi$. But I am not sure how further one can go from here. I found it here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286213/cotangent-sheaf-of-a-blow-up

Comment: Ok, random. What would it be to dualize this exact sequence? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $$0 \longrightarrow T_{E/Z} \longrightarrow T_{\widetilde{X}} \longrightarrow \pi^{*}T_{X} \longrightarrow 0 $$ right or wrong?

Comment: I suppose you are a new user, so you may not know this. One should write @[user name without the square brackets], so that the user in question gets notified. Applying the functor $Hom(-, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is not always exact and hence you cannot say this immediately. I am not sure if there is a map $T_{\widetilde{X}} \rightarrow \pi^*T_X$ as I have said before tat tangent sheaf doesnot behave well with respect to pullbacks.

Comment: @random123. Really, I'm a newbie here in the forum, Thanks for the tip and also for answering my question in the previous comment.

Comment: @random123. Taking the opportunity to learn a little more, which means: doesn't behave well with respect to pullbacks? Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question but I would certainly count existence of a map $T_{\widetilde{X}} \rightarrow \pi^* T_X$ as behaving well wrt to pullbacks. If the morphisms are smooth, then the tangent sheaf behaves well. Since, you said you are a beginner, let me suggest that it might be helpful to gain some background on relative differentials, cotangent sheaves if you do not.

Comment: @random123. I was looking at the exact sequences from Fulton's book (Intersection Theory) that involve blow up. (lemma 15.4 in my edition). When it comes to blow up over a positive dimension  subvariety, I have some questions and find little material available to study. For example, How to study the stability of the tangent  sheaf of $ \widetilde{X} $? Thank you.

Comment: In the lemma you mention, there are no exact sequence like the one you mention in the comments above. I realize that it would be ideal to have the short exact sequence you mentioned, but sometimes ideal things may not hold. Again something like this is true if you are looking at smooth morphisms but proper birational maps are far from it. I myself am not an expert so maybe there is something to the sort you need but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @random123. thank you for your attention. Success to you.I will continue to study blow up, this really catches my attention.